# iPhone not updating css on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I have a simple div that I add margin to on window resize that isn't getting run on an orientation change of the iPhone.

The alert works so I'm not sure why the css isn't getting changed also. I am using bootstrap and jquery.

Could anyone help me figure out why it wouldn't be running?

```
<div id="doughnut_container" class="col-md-5" style="position:relative;padding:0;">
    <canvas id="weekly_doughnut_data"></canvas>
     <div id="doughut_label_container" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;">
         <span id="doughnut_label" style="display:block;font-size:20px;font-weight:700;color:#333333;line-height:25px;"></span>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="chart_container" class="col-md-7" style="padding:0;">hi</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).resize(function()
{   
    alert("this works on orientation change");
    $("#doughnut_label").css("margin-top", ($("#doughnut_container").height()/2)-25);
});
```

Comment: don't rely on orientation change. I think it's very buggy. Instead, check for the resize and then determine if window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight to determine portrait/landscape

Comment: I have both orientation change and resize. Even if I take one out for the other, Both don't work. @dzny

Comment: Well the only other thing I can suggest is to make your code more uniform. For example, you lack brackets in your IF statement, and therefore I can't be sure if that section is being interpreted properly. I'm not comfortable/familiar with bracketless syntax, so maybe it's correct, i dunno.

Comment: The syntax is fine because it works. It just doesn't work on an orientation change. I appreciate your help but I'm not sure you fully understand my questions. @dzny

Comment: Works for me with the code you provided, plus of course including jquery...

Comment: @nvioli hmm thats wierd, do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/50qm88qu/
tested with chrome's mobile emulator.